# Is TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA secure?

Tags: ciphers, tomcat

I was wondering whether TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA is secure.
We have added it within the ciphers tag of the Tomcat configuration file.

Comment: well, a quick google search for "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA" turns up a lot of articles saying that it isn't

Comment: or are you asking about the typo you originally had in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RC4 in TLS is subject to [bias problems](https://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2013/03/12/attack-of-week-rc4-is-kind-of-broken-in/). In a pragmatic sense, while this has been exploited in lab conditions, it isn't very likely that you'll fall victim to it in practice. However, the cost of disabling RC4 suites is usually zero; the only systems that still have no AES support are Windows XP on Internet Explorer, and if you're still supporting such clients then you have much bigger problems than RC4.

(EDIT: As per Thomas' comment below, XP doesn't support ECDHE either, so this suite still wouldn't work on XP anyway)

TL;DR - disable it, there's no good reason to keep it around.

Comment: Actually Windows XP + IE would not support ECDHE anyway, so they would not be able to use TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA.

Comment: Good catch, I hadn't considered the lack of ECDHE support.

Comment: Is that SHA-1, perchance?

Comment: ... next you're gonna tell me that SHA-1 isn't supported by XP either (iirc they added support in SP3 or one of the later patches)

Comment: WinXP SP3 among other things added **SHA2** (for certs; TLS below 1.2 doesn't use SHA2 for KDF or HMAC) which ca 2008 NIST was proposing to mandate in 2011 -- although they actually didn't until 2014, and CABforum+browsers 2015+; SHA1 had been there a long time (since NT I think). Server2003 never got an SP for this and needed a hotfix.